# Call to undefined method Slice in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have this function,

```
public function getWall(){
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('f');
    $q->leftJoin("f.profilo", 'p');
    $q->leftJoin("p.utente", 'u');
    $q->where('(f.foto_eliminata IS NULL OR f.foto_eliminata != 1)');
    $q->andWhere('p.fase_registrazione = :fase');
    $q->andWhere('u.locked = :false');
    $q->slice(0, 20);
    $q->setParameter(':fase', 100);
    $q->setParameter('false', false);
    $q->orderBy('f.created_at', 'desc');
    $dql = $q->getQuery();
    $results = $dql->execute();

    return $results;
}
```

but I get this error,

```
Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::slice()
```

Comment: `Query Builder` has no method `slice()`. But collection has `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection::slice()` here is more inforamtion: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Comment: thanks for the comment, i try to add fetch="EXTRA_LAZY" in my leftJoin Entity (p and u) but i have the same error...I have to keep $q->slice(0, 20);?

Comment: wanted to answer in comments, but the answer was too big, hope it will help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so, u get this error, cause `QueryBuilder` has no such method. But `Collection` has. If u want to use slice, a possible variant is:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections;
public function getWall(){
    $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
        ->leftJoin("f.profilo", 'p')
        ->leftJoin("p.utente", 'u')
        ->where('(f.foto_eliminata IS NULL OR f.foto_eliminata != 1)')
        ->andWhere('p.fase_registrazione = :fase')
        ->andWhere('u.locked = :false')
        ->setParameter('fase', 100)
        ->setParameter('false', false)
        ->orderBy('f.created_at', 'desc')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

      // $result typed as array 
      return new Collections\ArrayCollection($result))->slice(0,20); // convert array to collection, then slice 
 }
```

By the way, it is not a good idea to 'limit' result of the query in a such way.
U can use `setMaxResults(20)`, and not to select all objects at all.

About lazy collections (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html): after selecting `result` objects, u can take some object from `result` collection: `$r = $result[0]` after that:

```
$portfilos = $r->getPortfolio(); // returns for example Collection with some objects;
                                 // its Lazy, without SQL query!

$portfolios->slice(0, 20); // queries first 20 potfolios
```

To use `slice` is a rather good idea, if u have lots of objects in some relation.

p.s. sry, mb I didn't recognized your problem, but tried :)

**EDITED**
fixed errors in code.

Comment: Thanks @DaunnC, i try your script but i have the same error http://pastebin.com/MzkyiSbn. I want use slice because then i want take the rows form 20 to 40 for example...thanks :). I do it in Repository file

Comment: Hm, I'll try my script above, and will find error :) very interesting.. btw, to decide this 'slice' problem:
u can set an offset, and then limit rows:
`->setFirstResult(20)->setMaxResults(20);` here, u can find more info about qb:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: i read this "bug" http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#first-and-max-result-items-dql-query-only

Comment: y, but what I made: select object ids with neccesasry offset and limit; after that make select `IN` selected ids, with neccesary joins. but mb it is not the best variant (dunno event how to make better), but better than select all objects from db, and then slice it

Comment: Maybe the best solution is clean query? (mysql)

Comment: I fixed example, yes, `getResult` returns array, not collection, so u cant use `slice`. Clean SQL is better for massive operations. DQL it is ORM, made to help and not to write SQL queries, more over it is not related to dbms, so u can easily migrate from dbms to dbms. Its your choice, u can use native queries if u want :)